# Whats the best way to separate men and women products in prestashop?

Tags: categories, prestashop

Can we separate products for men and women using any method other than categories, and which would be easy to configure?

Comment: Adding an attribute gender or similar which is either men/women/others might work.

Answer (score 0):

you could instead use categories like Clothing, Accessories, Shoes, Jewelry etc.. You would have to specify in the product title or description if it is for Male or Females, although it will likely be quite obvious.

Comment: Or add a custom attribute, or use the default attributes system.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately - I also could not find a specifications field where one could do things like that. I hope someone puts it into next version of Prestashop. It is possible in current Prestashop 1.5.5 by adding multiple categories to a single product where men or women could also be selected as an additional category but not the default category.